# Packetloss issues, maybe related to different gateways on two network interfaces (DHCP)

Tags: networking

I am struggling with a server where I have two network interfaces connected to two different networks with different gateways each. I don't have access to the switch configuration and ACLs but the claims on "the other side" are that "everything is well set up".

The configuration is very minimal, using `netplan` on an Ubuntu 20.04 server:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/99_config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
```

and here is the network (this is the actual configuration, nothing is obfuscated)

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:ee:08:10:07:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.131.161.10/24 brd 10.131.161.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 20579sec preferred_lft 20579sec
    inet6 fe80::f6ee:8ff:fe10:740/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens1f0np0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:3d:1a:e8:6c:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:ee:08:10:07:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.189.161.110/24 brd 10.189.161.255 scope global dynamic eno2
       valid_lft 20579sec preferred_lft 20579sec
    inet6 fe80::f6ee:8ff:fe10:741/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: ens1f1np1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:3d:1a:e8:6c:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

As you can see, two different networks `10.131.161.10/24` and `10.189.161.110/24` on two interfaces.

So far so good, everything works fine, but...

from time to time (last time right after an `apt-get upgrade` and currently it just happened over night, without any interaction), the server's network ends up ina state where it has a packet loss of around 90%.

```
--- ecap-s010 ping statistics ---
485 packets transmitted, 40 received, 91.7526% packet loss, time 490417ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.222/0.298/0.348/0.025 ms
```

From that point on I can barely connect via SSH: I have to do 100s of tries and if I am lucky, I catch a short time window where packets are routed correctly, which is enough to establish the connection. If I manage this, I have a stable SSH connection (most of the time).

The traffic dump reveals that somehow the echo reply is coming from the other interface (which is a different network)! If I ping `10.131.161.10` in this erroneous state, the answer is (most of the time) sent back on the other interface which is assigned to `10.189.161.110`.

**The only way to get out of this state is to pull the network cable from the `ens1f0np0` interface (`10.189.161.110`) and plug it back again.** After that, everything works as before, for a couple of days. I could not figure out any event which can be associated to this, there are no messages in `dmesg` whatsoever. The only time it was really related to an interaction was when I executed `apt-get upgrade`, which probably triggered some reconfiguration but I don't know what it was. Other times it happens randomly.

I don't have any fancy IP tables configuration. This is basicaly it:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -m comment --comment "Grafana" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.131.161.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.131.161.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8086 -m comment --comment "Grafana Agents"-j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Do you have any ideas how to debug this, or what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a multi-homed host you need to configure routing so that it knows which networks are reachable over which interface.

In your current configuration, each interface has received a default route from the DHCP server of the network segment it is connected to. Consequently, your server will believe that it can reach every IP address over either of the two interfaces, and is free to choose between them. (Except for addresses in one of the two directly connected networks 10.131.161.10/24 and 10.189.161.110/24, where it will prefer the direct link.) You can verify this by displaying and inspecting the routing table with the command `ip route`.

However, as witnessed by the packet loss you are experiencing, only one of the two interfaces actually works for reaching the public internet. So you need to fix your routing configuration to tell your server which of the two default routes is the correct one. One way of doing that is by adding `route-metric` entries to your `/etc/netplan/99_config.yaml` file as illustrated in the Netplan configuration example at https://netplan.io/examples/#connecting-multiple-interfaces-with-dhcp .

Depending on your network topology you may also need additional static routes. You should discuss that with your network team.

Comment: Many thanks, that makes perfect sense! I just applied `dhcp4-overrides: route-metric: 100` to `eno1` and `200` to `eno2` and it works now. I'll check with the network admins on the gateways for further configuration.